# Proving that between any 2 real numbers there is a compact set.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I want to prove that: Between any 2 real numbers there is a compact set. 
Could anyone help me in this, please? or tell me what theorems is this statement a consequence of?

Comment: If $x<y$ then $\{\frac{x+y}{2}\}$ is compact.

Comment: between any 2 real numbers, there are 2 other real numbers. Those can make up a closed interval, then you just have to show a closed interval is compact

Comment: how do you know that between any 2 real numbers there are 2 other real numbers? may be this is by the density of $\mathbb{R}$, correct? @Vsotvep

Comment: @hopefully indeed, this uses the density property. Note that the singleton set from Robert is a special case of my answer (but also a lot easier to prove)

Comment: I think the set you gave contains a point ..... so how is this compact?@RobertZ

Comment: @hopefully try the definition of compactness :)

Comment: @hopefully Any "singleton" is compact. Just apply the definition of compactness.

Comment: More explicitly, you can divide the interval $(x,y)$ in thirds and then take the closure of the "middle" subinterval. For example, if you wish to show that between $0$ and $1$ there is a compact set you can consider $[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]$. This can be generalized. There are, of course, other ways of doing so (uncountably many!).

Comment: @Vsotvep: I don't know about "a lot easier". You might as well just write $[\frac{2x+y}{3},\frac{x+2y}{3}]$. Just as easy, IMHO.

Comment: @tomasz I meant, proving compactness is a lot easier for a singleton than for a closed interval. There's only one element that could be in your union of opens / converging sequence / whichever definition is used

Comment: @Vsotvep: Ah. Yes, that is true.

Comment: There is a Cantor set between any two real numbers. There is a theorem that every Cantor set could be split into continuum many disjoint Cantor sets. Take one of those, it is compact.

Comment: @Mirko Killing a fly with a sword

Comment: @Robert_Z Please turn your comment into an answer, as a conclusion to this discussion.